# Can someone tell me why is it throwing syntax error in the query?

Tags: c#, database

It says I have a problem in my syntax but I don't know how to fix it. My database does contain these columns.

```
string Query = "INSERT into Users (full_name, email, password, admin) VALUES (@name,@email,@password,@admin)";

try
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@" provider=Microsoft.ace.Oledb.12.0; data source=" + dbString);

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", nameTB.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailTB.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passTB.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admin",'0');

    cmd.CommandText = Query;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: You can place a breakpoint near `cmd.CommadText` and check what the actual query is generated. Also you can copy and run the query in SQL management studio to know the exact error. Also check if any of your parameters you are passing aren't null

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Have you verified that none of your parameters are a null string?

Comment: What does the error say? Most likely it already explains what's wrong

Comment: Can you post the error message here?

Comment: the paramaters are filled by me on the form so it is not null

Comment: @EdPlunkett the connection string shows it's Access

Comment: @kipatbarzel1 *what is the error message ?* (strong suggestion)

Comment: syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Comment: it is VISUAL STUDIO and MICROSOFT ACCESS

Comment: Check table and column names

Comment: I didn't think `OleDbCommand` supported named parameters.

Comment: @Amy OleDbCommand always supported named parameters. It's the underlying provider that may or may not support them, in this case Jet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
string Query = "INSERT into Users ([full_name], [email], [password], [admin]) VALUES (@name,@email,@password,@admin)";
```

since password is a reserved keyword in OLE DB, as you can see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/321266?wa=wsignin1.0).

Answer (score 4):

If you [google for the error message](https://www.google.gr/search?q=syntax+error+in+INSERT+INTO+statement&oq=syntax+error+in+INSERT+INTO+statement&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.391j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8), you'll find that the first result warns that you [can't use reserved words in Access SQL statements](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/892608).

Looking into the [list of Jet 4.0 reserved words](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/248738) you'll see that `PASSWORD` is a reserved word.

You'll have to rename your column or enclose it in square brackets, eg `[Password]`